# Create rectangle with contents for AR SpriteKit application, programatically

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, augmented-reality, arkit

I created a new augmented reality app project in Xcode 9 with the content technology set to `SpriteKit`.

This generated a template project which places this little guy in the centre of your current view when you tap on the screen.

[image]

I wish to create something which looks a little like this instead of the placeholder emoji:

[image]

The idea behind this is to be able to set the `Name`, `Type` and `Rating` String values in code and create an `SKNode` object from that, to place in the centre of the screen.

I understand how to create a rectangle:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.

    //more of a square than a rectangle.. 
    var rect = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
    rect.fillColor = SKColor.white
    rect.position = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    return rect;
}
```

^ which gives me a white square on the screen

But how can I place text on top of that, as part of the same 'object' as it were? Is that possible? I've not been able to come across a solution to this anywhere and I'm not sure how to implement it.

EDIT:

Here is what I created based on a suggestion in the comments:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.

    let rect = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))
    rect.fillColor = SKColor.white
    rect.position = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    let nameNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Name")
    nameNode.fontSize = 10
    nameNode.fontColor = UIColor.black

    let typeNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Type")
    typeNode.fontSize = 10
    typeNode.fontColor = UIColor.black

    let ratingNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Rating")
    ratingNode.fontSize = 10
    ratingNode.fontColor = UIColor.black

    rect.addChild(nameNode)
    rect.addChild(typeNode)
    rect.addChild(ratingNode)

    return rect;
}
```

The text is all bundled together in the centre of the rectangle however. How can I align the labels like in my concept image above?

Plus the text seems to be very pixelated, any suggestions on particular settings I need to apply to combat this?

Comment: SKLabelNode as a child

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Hi, that's helped a lot! Thanks. I just have one last issue, how can I align my text labels like in my desired outcome concept image? (Please see Edit for updated code and suggest any improvements if you can - would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: in all honesty, I would use the SKS builder to build a scene visually that is laid out the way you want it, and then load the scene using `SKNode(fileNamed:)` instead of your SKShapeNode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Okay, thanks, I'll investigate how to create one using SKS builder.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Okay, so I successfully managed to create a custom scene using the builder. How can I access the properties of that `.sks` file so I can change the text of the labels? 

Also, replacing my code with:         `let node = SKNode(fileNamed: "CustomScene")
        
        return node;` doesn't do anything. I think I've misunderstood something?

Comment: make sure that the sks file is getting added to your build,  you need to go into the build settings (look it up if you do not know how) to make sure it got added.  You access the properties the same way you access any other nodes properties, not sure what you need to access

Comment: @Knight0fDragon When I return that `SKNode(fileNamed: "CustomScene")` my application crashes and I get the following error message: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Cant add body, already exists in a world', reason: 'Cant add body <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{-375, -667}, {750, 1334}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}], already exists in a world'`  - any ideas?

Comment: yes, it tells you exactly what your problem is, your physics body already exists in a world, and you are attempting to add it to a new world.  Sounds to me like you are attempting to add the node multiple times to the scene

Comment: From the template app, I literally created another `.sks` file with a white rectangle and three child label nodes on top. Then changed the code within the `view` function to what you suggested so I don't understand how I can be adding the node more than once if I only tap on the screen one time. Programmatically it works just fine, perhaps your suggestion isn't as simple as changing it to `let node = SKNode(fileNamed: "CustomScene") return node;`?

Comment: `func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode?` Gets called with each new anchor point created. Once ARKit makes the 2nd anchor point, your app should crash.  The old method made a new SKShapeNode everytime, this new method is using the same SKNode

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of this error message but it's proving a little confusing. By using the same `SKNode`, do you mean that the 'rectangle' and labels are being used from a 'template' and I can just create instances of that 'template'? Is it bad practice to create a new `SKShapeNode` every time? Would you be able to show me an example of how to use the same `SKNode` from the template project generated by Xcode? In my AR view, I'd eventually like to generate multiple rectangles from an array of objects which contain the `name`, `type` and `rating` attributes so your approach seems to m

Comment: seems to make sense, I'm not sure how to get it working that's all